# jQuery form validation - Report all errors at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I've been messing around with a validation like this for about a year now:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    $('#contact-form').submit(function(){
        var name = $('#inputnimi').val(),
            email = $('#inputemail').val(),
            message = $('#inputmessage').val();

            var nameerror = "<h4>Puuttuva kenttä</h4>",
            emailerror = "<h4>Puuttuva kenttä</h4>",
            messageerror= "<h4>Puuttuva kenttä</h4>";

            if(name == ""){
                $('.message-console').html(nameerror);
                return false;
            }

            if(email == ""){
                $('.message-console').html(emailerror);
                return false;
            }

            if(message == ""){
                $('.message-console').html(messageerror);
                return false;
            }
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "contact.php",
            data:  form-data,
            dataType: "text",
            error: function(){alert("ERROR");

            },
            success: function() {
                alert("success");
            }


            });
            return false;



    });
});
```

However, I don't like this because:

- It checks errors one by one, which is annoying on long forms
- I know there's a better way to do it

And I was wondering how I'm going to validate all the fields on one click, and all I could manage to think is something like this, which is obliviously never going to work:

```
if(name||email||message == ""){
$('.message-console').html(errors);
return false;
}
```

So I want to validate the form **without** any plugins, and show all errors at once, if there's any. But how?

Comment: although you don't wish to use a plugin, reading the source code of jQuery's validate plugin is very illuminating.  It can already do what you're trying to, so it's a good place to learn how.

Comment: @dnagirl I can't find it anywhere, link?

Comment: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
if(!(name&&email&&message))
{
    //error logic
}
```

However if any of the values is equal to **0** the validation will be triggered again, so you better use

```
if((name&&email&&message)=="")
{
    //error logic
}
```

Comment: And why would `name or email or message is equal to empty` work properly?

Comment: It is not OR it is logical conjuction, actually the code above means If any of the fields has empty value trigger the validation.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction#Applications_in_computer_engineering

Answer (score 0):

Well don't have it return false each time. Then you could have something like:

```
$('.message-console').html('');

if(name == ""){
  $('.message-console').append(nameerror);
 }
 /*others*/
```

Although I'd do what dnagirl suggested and use http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/ - It's not that bad as far as extra plugins AND it so easy to use.

Comment: I really don't want to use a plugin for validation, but thanks for tip.